# Finding next gap within values

Tags: sql, orm

Suppose I have the following table:

```
id  name  base   index
0   A     2      0
1   B     2      2
2   C     2      4
3   D     2      6
4   E     2      8
5   F     2      10
```

So, index = base * i, where i is the position of that row in a sequence.

From time to time, some rows are deleted, for instance, if I delete rows named C and D:

```
id  name  base   index
0   A     2      0
1   B     2      2
4   E     2      8
5   F     2      10
```

New rows are always added after the last, so the next row would be MAX(index)+base=12 in this case, but the gap left between values in the index column due to the deleted rows would be a problem after some time. If instead of inserting last I insert it in the first available gap, the problem won't happen.

So, I doubt any queries to find the first available gap would be as efficient as the MAX(index), but what would the most efficient solution be? Maybe it's good enough.

In case it's not clear, I need to find the first row 'a' such that the row with the closest upper index value is more than a.index + a.base.

This is meant for an application using an ORM for any SQL databases, so it has to be strictly standard SQL.

**edit**

This is a simplification of the real table and the real problem, and I'm looking for a solution using the base and index columns only. Solutions involving adding new columns or indexing in other table are not practical for my application.

**edit 2**

It seems the base column is making it more complicated, but that isn't essential. The problem can be reduced to a table like:

```
id  name  index
0   A     0
1   B     1
4   E     4
5   F     5
```

Where I need to find the first row 'a' such that the row with the lowest index that's higher than a.index + x. In this case x = 1.

Enumerating without ordering first or leveraging on the id aren't reliable solutions, since those can change. For instance, a solution has to work if the rows are like this too:

```
id  name  index
0   A     0
23  F     5
45  E     4
90  B     1
```

Comment: I doubt that an ORM's query language can tackle such problem for any database. Most ORMs cater to common denominator, and such problem is hard to solve if there's no windowing function. Afaik no ORMs has abstracted windowing function yet, most decently capable windowing functions only came recently to major RDBMS. On Postgresql, version 8.4(2009); and even SQL Server 2005 has windowing function, since er.. 2005, it's only on SQL Server 2012 that LAG and LEAD windowing function is supported; and even running total `(SUM OVER())` doesn't work on SQL Server 2008

Comment: If it's really true that always index = base * i, then you're storing the same information twice (i.e., the database is not normalized).  You could calculate "index" on the fly.

Comment: @MichaelBuen even if the ORM can't deal with the problem, I can use raw SQL but it still have to be compatible with all databases supported by the ORM.

Comment: @gcbenison I'm not storing twice since I'm not storing i, but this is a simplification of the real table. It's actually much more complicated than that and index is encoded across several columns which serve other purposes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me what your question means if there are multiple values of "base" in the table. Does the "row with the closest upper index value" have to have the same value of "base", for example?

In any case, this might be a start, if you are using a SQL platform that implements the function LEAD(). You may have to rephrase TOP in the appropriate dialect. Replace 999999999 with any value greater than the largest possible value of index+base.

```
with LeadAdded as (
  select 
    lead(index,1,999999999) over (order by index) as nxt,
    *
  from yourTable
)
  select top (1) *
  from LeadAdded
  where nxt > index + base;
  order by index
```

Comment: Yes, it does have the same value of base, but this whole thing will happen with a where clause filtering that already.

Comment: Even if the platform has LEAD(), woudn't that work only for the next physical row?

Comment: Pedro, I don't know what you mean by "next physical row." Where I used LEAD in this example, it will provide the index value in "the row with the lowest index that's higher than a.index + x," which is how you phrased what you want. The OVER clause defines what "next" means for the LEAD function, and the outer WHERE clause with TOP (1)  and ORDER selects the single lowest index higher than index+base.

Comment: I meant next row ordering by id, but forget it. LEAD() wasn't clear for me when I asked that. That works, but unfortunately I can't depend on it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting the row, can you add another column to mark it as available? Then you could select the MIN(id) from your table that is marked 'AVAILABLE' with the given base. If not found, then you insert. That way you can avoid having gaps, keep a history, and maybe simplify?

Comment: Not really. This is just a simplification of the problem, the actual table is a lot more complex and there are nested values which would have to be marked as available in cascade too, making it actually more complex than the compaction maintenance operation I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Most SQL dialects support window functions, so you could do something like:

```
select min(id)
from 
(
   select t.*, 
      row_number() over (order by id) as rownum
   from t
)
where id <> rownum
```

This returns the first id that is out of sequence.

I might suggest, something similar to the first suggestion.  When a row is deleted, store the id in another table of "available" ids.  When inserting, look in this table first.  If none are available then create a new one.

Comment: If I understand it right, that would work for the first run ever, but then on the next one that id would still be out of sequence, since it wasn't changed, but the next index in that sequence is filled. Not only that, but ids will be very volatile on this application, because a row can have is base and index changed to another and leave that base set entirely. I really need a solution that uses only base and index.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way that wouldn't depend on anything beyond standard SQL would be to keep a separate table of "all possible values of `index`":

```
SELECT * FROM indices LIMIT 7;
+------+
| idx  |
+------+
|    0 |
|    2 |
|    4 |
|    6 |
|    8 |
|   10 |
|   12 |
+------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then let's say your users table looks like this, with the first gap occurring at index=4:

```
SELECT * FROM users;
+------+------+------+------+
| id   | name | base | idx  |
+------+------+------+------+
|    0 | A    |    2 |    0 |
|    1 | B    |    2 |    2 |
|    4 | E    |    2 |    8 |
|    5 | F    |    2 |   10 |
+------+------+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` with the indices table to find this first gap:

```
SELECT indices.*
FROM indices
LEFT JOIN users
USING(idx)
WHERE users.idx IS NULL
ORDER BY idx
LIMIT 1;

+------+
| idx  |
+------+
|    4 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This will fail if the first gap occurs after the end of the indices table, in which case you could detect the error and extend the indices table.